# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT zip archive does not include classes.dex

Tags: android-studio

I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days. I can't debug my application on my android device using Android Studio.

This is the error I get:

[INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

When I look at the logs, it says "zip archive does not include classes.dex"

So the problem is that classes.dex isn't being built into the APK. This is true since the file size of my APK is now around 1MB whereas it used to be around 1.3MB.

I have tried everything, but I have no idea why classes.dex isn't being built into my APK. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Joaquin

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your build, and build the app again.. Make sure you've added the activities to the Android manifest. Once you get the apk use 7zip to view apk and check if there is classes.dex or use native zip viewer if on Linux. And if nothing still works try synchronizing the build files so that gradle can detect non ide changes.

Comment: classes.dex is not being built into the apk. I just confirmed so via 7-Zip. I tried all your suggestions to no avail - can you think of anything else?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest sdk tools and Android studio. And make sure that you have Jdk 1.6 only. Since later versions are not supported for building.

Comment: I have decided to go back to Eclipse. To anyone having this problem: I spent over 7 hours looking for a solution. There's very little info online. Hopefully this gets fixed in the future.

Comment: It's not a common issue, hence you don't find much on the Internet, mine works perfectly without any problems. Although, I prefer ant a little more than gradle, so I use eclipse a little more.

Comment: Try unchecking "build automatically" and clean and build project.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried disabling my antivirus (Avast), cleaning and rebuilding the app and then restarting Android Studio.

Those steps worked and I can now debug my application on my android device again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that classes.dex is only generated if your project contains Java classes. So if you are using the NDK in combination with native activities, there won't be no Java code at all and therefore no classes.dex. In that case, you have to set the hasCode attribute in the manifest to false because otherwise dexopt will be looking for it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#code